# iText alignment cell 6 levels

Tags: java, pdf, alignment, itext

In my project, I'm using iText to print a dynamic table on PDF.

There are 6 different levels in my enumeration. I want to align every level a little bit more to right.

In iText, there is a function: **cell.setHorizontalAlignment()**

The problem is that you can only choice between: LEFT, CENTER and RIGHT
Any possible solutions for this?

An example of what I want:

```
1
  2
    3
      4
        5
          6
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to define the *indentation* (you talk of *alignment*, but I assume you meant *alignment*) at the level of a `PdfPCell`? Why not define the indentation at the level of a `Paragraph`? You'll have to rephrase your question eliminating all potential causes of confusion: are you talking about alignment or indentation (or maybe you refer to *padding*)? **Why** do you need a table? Do the levels correspond with rows? It's a strange question.

Comment: Perfect! Indeed I have changed the alignment with padding and this is working! If you post this comment as answer, I will mark it as correct :-)! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the indentation inside a cell, one way is to change the indentation at the level of the `Paragraph` objects you're adding to the cell. Another way would be to change the padding of the cell (you can change the padding on all sides, or on the right, level, top and bottom separately).